# Google FIT API - C# Function to calculate a datetime to NanoSeconds

Tags: google-api, google-fit, oauth2-playground

I am trying to call the GoogleFIT weight API using the following code -

```
public class GoogleFitImport
{
    private static readonly DateTime zero = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static long ToCSNanoseconds(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateTime centuryBegin = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1);
        DateTime currentDate = dt;

        long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks;
        TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(elapsedTicks);

        return elapsedTicks * 100;
    }

    public static DateTime FromJavaNanoseconds(long? nanoseconds)
    {
        if (nanoseconds == null)
            nanoseconds = 0;
        return FromJavaMiliseconds((nanoseconds.Value / (10 ^ 6)));
    }

    public static DateTime FromJavaMiliseconds(long mili)
    {
        return zero.AddMilliseconds((double)mili);
    }

    public static void InsertToGoogleFit()
    {
        string UserId = "me";
        List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>> measures = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>>();
        measures.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>(new DateTime(2022, 01, 01, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), 10.1f));
        measures.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>(new DateTime(2022, 01, 02, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), 10.2f));
        measures.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>(new DateTime(2022, 01, 03, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), 10.3f));

        //  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write
        var clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // From https://console.developers.google.com
        var clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // From https://console.developers.google.com

        //Scopes for use with the Google Drive API
        string[] scopes = new string[]
        {
            FitnessService.Scope.FitnessBodyWrite,
            FitnessService.Scope.FitnessBodyRead,
        };

        string credPath = "other_token.json";
        // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
        (                
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile("D:\\Office\\Hack-a-thon\\Desktop.json").Secrets,
            scopes,
            Environment.UserName,
            CancellationToken.None,
           // new FileDataStore("Google.Fitness.Auth", false)
           new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
        ).Result;


        FitnessService fitnessService = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "FromLibraCsvToGoogleFit" //Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
        });

        //FitnessService fitnessService = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        //{
        //    ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
        //    ApiKey = "AIzaSyBFtKKt0I7uf-Tk7DYun7dxcas_1vl1ybA",
        //});


        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource()
        {
            Type = "raw", //""derived",
            Application = new Google.Apis.Fitness.v1.Data.Application()
            {
                Name = "maweightimport"
            },
            DataType = new DataType()
            {
                Name = "com.google.weight",
                Field = new List<DataTypeField>()
                {
                    new DataTypeField() {Name = "weight", Format = "floatPoint"}
                }
            },
            Device = new Device()
            {
                Type = "scale",
                Manufacturer = "unknown",
                Model = "unknown",
                Uid = "maweightimport",
                Version = "1.0"
            }
        };

        //string dataSourceId = "derived:com.google.weight:{clientId}:unknown:unknown:maweightimport"
        string dataSourceId =
            $"{dataSource.Type}:{dataSource.DataType.Name}:{clientId.Split('-')[0]}:{dataSource.Device.Manufacturer}:{dataSource.Device.Model}:{dataSource.Device.Uid}";

        try
        {
            //DataSource googleDataSource = fitnessService.Users.DataSources.Create(dataSource, UserId).Execute();
            DataSource googleDataSource = fitnessService.Users.DataSources.Get(UserId, dataSourceId).Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //create if not exists
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            DataSource googleDataSource = fitnessService.Users.DataSources.Create(dataSource, UserId).Execute();
        }

        Google.Apis.Fitness.v1.Data.Dataset weightsDataSource = new Google.Apis.Fitness.v1.Data.Dataset()
        {
            DataSourceId = dataSourceId,
            Point = new List<DataPoint>()
        };

        DateTime minDateTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime maxDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        foreach (var weight in measures)
        {
            long ts = ToCSNanoseconds(weight.Key);
            weightsDataSource.Point.Add
            (
                new DataPoint()
                {
                    DataTypeName = "com.google.weight",
                    StartTimeNanos = ts,
                    EndTimeNanos = ts,
                    Value = new List<Value>()
                    {
                        new Value()
                        {
                            FpVal = weight.Value
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

            if (minDateTime > weight.Key)
                minDateTime = weight.Key;
            if (maxDateTime < weight.Key)
                maxDateTime = weight.Key;
        }

        weightsDataSource.MinStartTimeNs = ToCSNanoseconds(minDateTime) ;
        weightsDataSource.MaxEndTimeNs = ToCSNanoseconds(maxDateTime);

        string dataSetId = $"{ weightsDataSource.MinStartTimeNs }-{weightsDataSource.MaxEndTimeNs}";
        var save = fitnessService.Users.DataSources.Datasets.Patch(weightsDataSource, UserId, dataSourceId, dataSetId).Execute(); //ERROR HERE !
        //var read = fitnessService.Users.DataSources.Datasets.Get(UserId, dataSourceId, dataSetId).Execute();
    }
}
```

But as soon as I call the PATCH API for updating the weight -

```
fitnessService.Users.DataSources.Datasets.Patch
```

Code throws following error -

> "{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Invalid StartTimeNanos: com.google.weight [1991-01-01T12:00:00Z - 1991-01-01T12:00:00Z] [10.100000381469727] raw:com.google.weight:415313936941:unknown:unknown:maweightimport",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Invalid StartTimeNanos: com.google.weight [1991-01-01T12:00:00Z - 1991-01-01T12:00:00Z] [10.100000381469727] raw:com.google.weight:415313936941:unknown:unknown:maweightimport",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "invalidArgument"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n"

Any idea, what error I am making? I think its about the NanoSeconds calculations. If yes, how can I fix this?

Comment: Why is `ToCSNanoseconds` based on a date in 2001? The nanoseconds are nanos since unix epoch.

Comment: Notice that it's saying it thinks you are specifying dates in 1991 - that's 21 years after unix epoch. Similarly, 2022 is 21 years after 2001.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tries, found out that .Net added a new API in Version 4.6.

> Following APIs were added in .NET Framework 4.6; from release notes:
>
> Support for converting dates and times to or from Unix time
>
> The following new methods have been added to the DateTimeOffset
> structure to support converting date and time values to or from Unix time:
> DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds
> DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds
> DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds

So using the above APIs, the NanoSeconds calculations I have done is as follows-

```
public static long ToCSNanoseconds(DateTime dt)
{
     DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
     return new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() * 1000000;
}
```